# A certain part of the mesh isn't baked onto any map, like it is ignored

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

For some reason when I bake any kind of map for this object (diffusion, normal), this "handle" gets ignored: its parts do not appear on the map (images below), so when I apply the map on whole object, it appears with no textures. In fact there is another object that is literally just this handle and nothing else, and the map comes out completely blank. Therefore I would assume that there is something wrong with that certain "handle" shape, but I don't know what. **BLEND FILE IS INCLUDED**

Edit: the material that has the problem is "badmetal". This is material where I used texture nodes and baked the maps from. As seen in the images provided, that certain region, "the handle" is skipped for some reason, but the everything else ("the hatch") is baked fine. So I would assume the problem with that specific shape?

I am using default settings when baking (no direct and no indirect light when baking diffuse)

I will attach two images:

**the shape is selected on both UV and edit mode**

[image: the shape is selected on both UV and edit mode]

**the same image but with no selection so you see there is no color in those places:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The material here, "imetal", has a metallic value of 827.0.  Beyond the fact that this value doesn't make any sense (it should be in 0,1 range), it means that the object has no diffuse component, only glossy/specular.  Baking normals gives me nothing interesting because you didn't pack images, but doing a quick bump map and baking normals shows the indicated region baking just fine.

Comment: Hello, my apologies if I didn't explain myself correctly, but the problem is not with material "imetal". That is the material where I check my baked maps, like "hatch_color.jpg". My main problem is the material where I used texture nodes, from which I baked this map, "badmetal" it's called. And it has metallic value of 0. As you see on the images i provided, for some reason that certain region is skipped in the color map, the whole other mesh is baked fine. Thank you!

Comment: There is something bugged with mesh Cube.006, object frame handle.  How did you make it?  Did it involve any addons?  Something made some bad mesh.  It's not the material (problems persist on changed mats), it's the mesh (problems are removed upon export/import to .obj.)  Suspect a buggy importer-- look at what happens when you delete a face, edges remain; but delete edges, faces is deleted.  Behavior indicates some super bugged geometry.

Comment: Oh, and you should edit your question so that you're showing other people the actual thing you want them to look at (otherwise, they don't know, and they'll waste their time.)  People aren't necessarily going to look at the comments.

Comment: Thank you. I was assuming it was something with the mesh, I will try out your suggestions. If no success I will just redo the handle.

Comment: Oh, wait.  It's just that the mesh isn't assigned to the material.  It's drawing it as that mat, because it has no mat, but apparently baking isn't reading that.  Assign all faces to your material and it bakes okay.

Comment: Wow, thank you it did work. However it makes no sense to me, since if you look at the mesh in view port shading, the material is covering the mesh perfectly. So I don't know why the material was not assigned to that specific "handle". Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, here is what I tried before the map came out good:

- Recalculate normals for that specific part
- Reduced Island Margin when using "Smart UV project"
- Increased the angle limit by a little bit
- And finally (which I think the one that worked) assigned the material to the faces of the mesh, that was not appearing on the baked maps. (comment above)